# Prove that $G$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm getting a little lost with group theory so I'm revising notes and saw this little exercise that my professor left in the margin. I need some help as I can't really remember the results of elementary number theory:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n >1 $, and let $G = \{x\in \{1,2,...,n-1\} \mid \gcd(x,n)=1\}$. The group's binary operator is multiplication modulo $n$. Prove that $G$ is a group.

I know that I only need to show that it fulfills the $4$ properties of a group.

(G1) $\forall a,b \in G, ab \in G $. Since $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$, $\gcd(ab,n)=1$. (how to justify this?)

(G2) $\forall a,b,c \in G, (ab)c = abc \mod{n} = a(bc).$

(G3) For all $n$, $1 \in G$ and $1a = a1 = a$ for all $a\in G$. Hence, $1$ is the identity element.

(G4) From studying some examples of small n, I observed that $a$ is it's own inverse. But how do I show this? Is there a result that says that $\gcd(a,n)=1 \implies \gcd(a^2,n)=1$?

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)? It can help you to prove G1 and G4.

Comment: check this straigth forwards http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n

Comment: oh I think I did learn about Bezout's identity, only I've forgotten! Thank you for the links I'll go read them up and study the answers provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$1)$ Suppose $\gcd(a, n) = \gcd(b, n) = 1$. Then there are $x_{1}, y_{1}, x_{2}, y_{2} \in \Bbb Z$ such that:

$$x_{1}a+y_{1}n = 1 = x_{2}b+y_{2}n$$

Hence,

$$(x_{1}a+y_{1}n)(x_{2}b+y_{2}n) =x_{1}x_{2}ab + (y_{1}x_{2}b+x_{1}y_{2}a+y_{1}y_{2}n)n = 1 $$

Thus, $\gcd(ab,n) = 1$ by Bezout's lemma.

$4)$ Each element is not necessarily it's own inverse. However, for each $a$ such that $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, by Bezout's lemma, there are $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that

$$xa + ny = 1$$

Hence, reducing $\pmod n$, $x$ is an inverse for $a$ in $G$.

Feel free to comment if you need further suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

G1: If some prime $p$ divides $ab$ and $n$, then divides $a$ or $b$. Both cases are impossible since $hcf(a,n)=hcf(b,n)=1$.

G4: When $hcf(a,n)=1$ Bezout's identity says that there exist integers $x,y$ such that
$$ax+ny=1$$
that is
$$ax\equiv 1\pmod n$$
Therefore, $x$ is the inverse of $a$.

Respect to the last question: put $b=a$ in G1.